Issue With Xerces-C in Geant4
I am having an issue with Xerces-C in Geant4. It was working fine before I decided to update and upgrade my Homebrew packages. After updating, I am encountering the following error:
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message): Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_VERSION) (Required is at least version "3.2.4") Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindXercesC.cmake:112 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.5/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package) /Users/geant4/install/lib/cmake/Geant4/Geant4Config.cmake:305 (find_dependency) CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

To fix this, I tried configuring Geant4 with the new Xerces-C version using the following CMake command in the build directory:
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/geant4/install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DGEANT4_USE_GDML=ON -DGEANT4_BUILD_MULTITHREADED=ON -DXercesC_ROOT=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/xerces-c/3.2.5 -DGEANT4_USE_QT=ON -DGEANT4_INSTALL_EXAMPLES=ON -DGEANT4_INSTALL_DATA=ON -DGEANT4_USE_SYSTEM_EXPAT=OFF -DGEANT4_BUILD_TLS_MODEL=auto ..

However, I still encounter the same issue. How can I resolve this problem?

Have you cleared your cmake cache?

Yes! I tried with clearing the cashe as well.
